# Magento 1.9.3 Get Shipping Address From Observer With Event sales_order_place_after

Tags: magento-1.9, event-observer, shipping-address

I have a custom function that is triggered with event **sales_order_place_after**, I need to retrieve the shipping address in this function.

I tried `$observer->getCustomerAddress()`, but it didn't work. How could I get the shipping address?

This is my function

```
        public function SalesOrderPlaceAfter($observer)
        {

            $orderIds = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder()->getId();   
                if (!empty($orderIds)) 
                {
//This get me the shipping method. it's working.
    $shipping_method = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder()->getShippingMethod(); 

// this is not working, How can I get the shipping address?
    $shipping_address = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder()->getShippingAddress(); 
                }
        }
```

Comment: Can you add your `Observer.php` code to the question?

Comment: I've updated the question to include my custom function.

Comment: @MagentoLearner How to check shipping country before placing order, i mean if customer choose other country one of my products not eligible to place an order?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've loaded the Address object as per Rene's answer, here's how you'd get the fields;

```
$_shippingAddress = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder()->getShippingAddress();

echo $_shippingAddress->getFirstname();
echo $_shippingAddress->getLastname();
echo $_shippingAddress->getCompany();
echo $_shippingAddress->getStreetFull();
echo $_shippingAddress->getRegion();
echo $_shippingAddress->getCity();
echo $_shippingAddress->getPostcode();
echo $_shippingAddress->getTelephone();
echo $_shippingAddress->getCountryId();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$observer->getEvent()->getOrder()->getShippingAddress()
```

should get you the shipping address.

Comment: I tried your code, it only returned a "Object"

Comment: @xxx have you tried iterating through the Object, or directly calling part of it, e.g. `$observer->getEvent()->getOrder()->getShippingAddress()->getCountryId()`?

Comment: @RickyOdinMatthews I can get country ID with your code. How can I get the rest address information? Thanks.

Comment: `$observer->getEvent()->getOrder()->getShippingAddress()->getData()` will show you what elements the shipping address contains, you can then replace `getData()` with `getCountryId()` or other data you want to get.